# SSRS report - panels are multiplying in a report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a strange problem with SSRS reports. Please take a look at the image. It's hard to explain the problem. How can I fix these multiple panels?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the report from internet explorer, once you have the report opened, go to tools or click on (Alt + X), go to compatibility view, and add the server at which you are viewing the report to compatibility view list.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem. Do you have an idea how to prevent this problem from ocurring to other users? I thought about using GPO to set the compatibility for all the users on this website.

Comment: @BuahahaXD this is exactly what I did when I had this problem. You need to let IT administrators to use GPO to set the compatibility for all users on this website. There might be other solutions, like playing around with the java script for reporting services server, but I am not aware of any.